# Using raw_input causes problems with PyQt page loading

Tags: python, pyqt4, stdin, raw-input, qwebpage

I'm using PyQt4 to enter credentials into a domain login page and pull data from several additional pages in the domain. Everything works exactly as expected when supplying login or search credentials from within the code. When I open up raw_input to allow the user to enter information, it causes hang-ups trying to download one of the web-pages. I can't provide information on the page itself because it is on a corporate network, but it doesn't make sense that simply using raw_input would cause problems with QWebpage loads.

The QNetworkManager throws 1 of the expected 3 or 4 .finished signals and the QWebpage frame never throws the .loadfinished signal so it just hangs.

(I've tried to flushing stdin as well as seek(0) which gives me a bad file descriptor error). Has anyone run into such a problem before?

Comment: You can provide the code though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`raw_input` uses synchronous/blocking IO without giving Qt a chance to continue processing events in the background. Qt isn't really prepared for it's processing to be halted in this way. In theory it should just resume when raw_input is finished. But maybe in the meantime a timeout occurred or something like that. You really should use signal/event based input when using Qt.

If GUI interaction is ok you should try QInputDialog::getText because it looks like a blocking call from the outside but internally lets Qt to continue processing background jobs.

Comment: Constructing a dialog rather than using raw_input appears to eliminate the problem! It's seems weird that it's such a subtle failure... spent a ton of time dissecting the webkit portion of my code to no avail. I hope my pain can help out another novice. Thanks textshell!

Comment: The important part is that the dialog is a facility of qt, while `raw_input` is a python facility that doesn't cooperate with qt's internal background work. If Qt would offer an easy way to read from the console it would work too. It's actually possible to implement that. But that would be a lot more work than just using a dialog already provided by qt.